How do I select vertices in a model, including the backside?
I am attempting to select half of a Sphere—the bottom half, for instance. In Edit mode, I use the rectangular select tool to draw a shape covering the lower half of the sphere. Sometimes, the entire hemisphere is selected; other times, only the half facing me is chosen, leaving the entire back portion unselected. I can maneuver the mesh and then hold Shift while selecting more vertices, but there must be a method I am not understanding. How do I select an entire hemisphere of an object—including the backside, the opposite face—in Edit mode using the rectangular select tool?

Could you give an example of one of these "every tutorial" because I actually do not know what this is. Especially I have never heard of a button for a render window which has anything to do with selecting faces, since editing meshes is independent from rendering. But "select mesh faces on both sides" - are you talking about the X-Ray toggle button? But this has nothing to do with render windows.

It must be Wireframe or Xray view next to Rendered View.  The four square buttons in the top right of the viewport?

Could you please change the question to match the one in the screenshot, something like "How can I select vertices, including those on the backside?" because your question doesn't make sense asking about some Render button and then showing a screenshot that is about selecting vertices, that is why your question remains closed as needing details or clarity. Also this seems like an XY problem, what exactly are you trying to do? Are you referring to X-Ray btn? https://brandon3d.com/how-to-use-x-ray-view-mode-in-blender-3d/

Is this what you are asking for? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Vtcr0iOLqY

Hello thanks for clarifying the question. The answer is in the video I shared, by enabling the X-Ray mode which allows selecting everything everything covered in your box selction including vertices behind the model. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Vtcr0iOLqY

You can use X-Ray option for your scenario.

X-Ray (shortcut: Alt+Z) Make objects transparent, allowing you to see and select items that would otherwise
be occluded. The slider controls object opacity.


The Wireframe mode will also work.

Thank you so much for this lesson. The graphic speaks volumes. I knew I had selected the entire hemisphere before, but I got confused about which settings I used to achieve the desired result. I appreciate your attention.
